# at System.Data.DataColumn.set_Item : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am trying to perform the following operation and getting this exception

`moDataTable.ImportRow(oDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0))`

1. In oDataSet.Tables(0) there is one column of name "date_created" having a datatype "string"
2. In moDataTable there is the same column "date_created" having a datatype "DateTime"

I know this error is occurring just because of the different data types but the same code was working for me by last month and currently, the same code is working for my all colleagues and my all customers. I am trying to avoid the code changes as it's working for all other and just an issue with my system. I think it's system related issue can Someone help me with this. Suggestions for code changes are also welcome. But giving preference first for the system specific changes answer.

The shortest code is as following

```
Public Sub ImportDataAddedThroughPopup(ByVal aoDataRow As DataRow, Optional ByVal abMakeFinal As Boolean = False)
            moDataRow = aoDataRow
            Dim oDataSet As New DataSet
            Dim oDataTable As New DataTable
            oDataTable = moDataRow.Table.Clone
            oDataTable.ImportRow(moDataRow)

            oDataSet.Tables.Add(oDataTable)  
            
            moDataTable.ImportRow(oDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)) 'At this line it's giving an error
            moDataTable.AcceptChanges()

End Sub
```

The exception it is throwing is as follow:

> at System.Data.DataColumn.set_Item  :  String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store <10/19/2020 11:24:00 AM> in date_created Column.  Expected type is DateTime.

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Either parse date_created manually into DateTime with a custom string/culture, or change your app CurrentCulture so it will parse the date correctly. Note that if this is running on desktop instead of server, you will need to test it against various Windows culture setting

Comment: I believe I remember this question.

Comment: Hi @Martheen , Will you please give me some brief idea about the windows culture and app culture what exactly I need to check? it will help

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

I found but Haven't found any specific error in the system which I can fix so I decided to do code change and changes code as follows to solve this issue.
I was sure that oDataset.Tables(0) containing only one row so I replaced the affected column "date_created" having data type string to column "date_created" having data type DateTime

```
Public Sub ImportDataAddedThroughPopup(ByVal aoDataRow As DataRow, Optional ByVal abMakeFinal As Boolean = False)
        moDataRow = aoDataRow
        Dim newType = GetType(DateTime) 'Added code
        Dim dc As DataColumn = New DataColumn("DT_new", newType)    'Added code
        Dim oDataSet As New DataSet
        Dim oDataTable As New DataTable
        oDataTable = moDataRow.Table.Clone
        oDataTable.ImportRow(moDataRow)

        oDataSet.Tables.Add(oDataTable)  
        'Code block added [start]
         oDataSet.Tables(0).Columns.Add(dc)
         oDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)("DT_new") = FormatDateTime(moDataRow("date_created"), DateFormat.GeneralDate)
         oDataSet.Tables(0).Columns.Remove("date_created")
         dc.ColumnName = "date_created"
        'Code block added [End]
        
        moDataTable.ImportRow(oDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)) 'At this line it's giving an error
        moDataTable.AcceptChanges()
```

End Sub